# How do I call a C++ DLL from C#/WPF project

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

I have the below code:

```
namespace WPFMuskTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport
            ("myDll.DLL", 
             EntryPoint = "?Func1@FUllNameCopiedFromDependancyWalker",
             CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl
            )
        ]
        public static extern System.IntPtr Func1(out System.IntPtr handle, int type, out  DateTime date);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            // 
            // 
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.IntPtr MainParam;
            int thetype = 1
            DateTime date;

            System.IntPtr res = GetFxIRMoveForDate(out MainParam, thetype _til, out date);
        }
    }
}
```

The exe is in the same path as the called DLL and the function definitely exists in the DLL (verified in DependacyWalker) but I keep getting the error:

The function prototype being called is:

class __declspec(dllexport) OUR_DATE_TYPE
{
....
}

typedef unsigned long TYPE;
typedef DATE_TYPE OUR_DATE_TYPE;

```
namespace1
{
namespace2
{
void func1(MyClass &myclass, const TYPE& type, const DATE_TYPE& date);
}
}
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: We'd really need to see the signature of the method in the C# DLL to know if you typed the DllImport correctly.

Comment: Added the C++ prototype - I am guessing that is what you meant?

Comment: Can you provide the macro definitions of `TYPE` and `DATE_TYPE` ?

Comment: `MyClass myclass` and `IntPtr handle` might not correspond to each other, since `myclass` is not being passed as a pointer.

Comment: Sorry, have corrected a typo - please have another look!

Answer (score 1):

By default, c++ does not use the `cdecl` calling convention, it uses `stdcall`. You would probably have more success writing a c wrapper to the c++ api and calling that instead, because C has a well-defined [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).

EDIT: looking at your code again, I doubt `DateTime` is the same as the date type you're using in C++. If it's the wrong size, for example, this error could occur.

Comment: So should changing the calling convention to CallingConvention.Stdcall work?  I have tried that and the error is the same.  I am not sure it would go down well if I created another wrapper library in C for my wrapper in C# to work - surely this can be done?